# How to roll back the migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have successfully done three migrations.

20150109133619_add_items.rb:

```
class AddItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pros do |t|
      t.string :titlerr
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

20150109134955_add_col.rb:

```
class AddCol < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pros, :fieldname, :string
  end
end
```

20150109162301_del_col.rb:

```
class DelCol < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :pros, :fieldname
  end
end
```

Now I need to roll back the state before migration 20150109134955. I did the following:

```
rake db:rollback
```

The result is the following message:

```
==  DelCol: reverting =========================================================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

remove_column is only reversible if given a type./home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:128:in `invert_remove_column'
/home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:66:in `inverse_of'
........
........
........
/home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:126:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My second attempt was:

```
rake db:rollback VERSION=20150109134955
```

The result is the following message:

```
==  DelCol: reverting =========================================================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

remove_column is only reversible if given a type./home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:128:in `invert_remove_column'
/home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:66:in `inverse_of'
.....
.....
.....
/home/kalinin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:126:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Did you try adding `, :string` to 20150109162301 like the error message suggests?  What happened then?

Comment: please try to run `rake db:rollback --trace` and see the full trace, also post the trace here.

Comment: Please read the error message. It is trying to help you.

Comment: It isn't necessary to plead for help. We're here to help you if we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the datatype to 20150109162301_del_col.rb

```
class DelCol < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :pros, :fieldname, :string
  end
end
```